# When partitioning a huge table in postgres , how much is too much?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-performance

I have a huge table in Postgres with 10 million inserts per day, Since it's not feasible to keep all these data in a single table, we are splitting it based on the week. we are currently using Postgres table inheritance.

The weekly table currently has about 70 million rows and the data size is approximately 7 to 8 GB, This solution is not feasible long term as the number of data sources(devices) would increase in future.
What we are planning to do is to do declarative partitioning in Postgres and use the device id as the partitioning condition.
The idea is to divide the partition based on device id like so

0- 250 - 1st partition
250-500 - 2nd partition
..
..
..
45500 - 50000 - nth partition

But the problem is that we have to keep a minimum of 3 months' data, so the size of the partition will eventually add up to 100 million by the end of 3 months anyway.
I need to reduce the data in each partition, the two ways I'm planning to approach this issue is

1. reduce the number of devices in each partition
2. add a month constraint to partition

My question is if I do the above 2 methods the number of tables for 50,000 devices would be 500 and 2400 respectively, is that ok? or can I increase the number of partitions and get similar or improved performance.
This is running on a server with 32 cores and 256gb of ram.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is your goal: make deleting old, obsolete rows faster or making queries for a specific device ID faster?

Comment: Actually both. we don't need data prior to 3 months so deletion is a goal and also the query performance is mediocre now, I want to improve that also.

Comment: To make deleting old rows faster, you would need partition by range using a e.g. `timestamp` column. With that many devices, maybe sub-partitioning by hash on the device_id might help performance, but only if all queries (or at least the relevant ones) contain a range condition that selects one partition and a condition on the device id to pick the right partition for the device

Comment: With Postgres 12 or later, "thousands" of partitions should be OK, "tens of thousands" (or more) would probably still be a problem.